# How to rotate a line using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, rotation

Suppose I have an image `I` and a line `h1`. Using Matlab, I can draw the line (or segment) like this

```
h1 = plot( [l1 l1],[20 100], 'r');
```

Now I want to rotate the image `I` with an angle of 45°. So I used `imrotate` like this:

```
IR = imrotate(I,45);
```

Now, I want to rotate the line, how to do that using Matlab ?

I found the function `rotate`. I am trying this, but it is not working !

```
rotate(h1,[1 1],45);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rotate the line you can explicitly "rotate" the points defining the line by using the rotation matrix:

[image]

The centre of the rotation is defined by the "offset" added to the coordinates of the line's points:

In the following examples, the line is rotated around:

- the lower point of the line (offset = coordinates of the lower point of the line)
- the origin (0,0) (offset = 0)
- a point of the original line (offset = coordinates of a point of the line)

**Updated code**

```
% Definition of the L1 parameter
L1=13;
% Definition of the points A and B
A=[L1,20]
B=[L1,100]
x=[A(1) B(1)];
y=[A(2) B(2)];
% Definition of the offset
x_offset=[x(1) 0 x(1)];
y_offset=[y(1) 0 50];
for k=1:3
   figure
   % Plot of the original line
   plot(x,y,'r','linewidth',2)
   grid on
   hold on
   for a=10:10:350
      % Definitin of the rotation angle
      % a=45;
      t=a*pi/180;
      % Definition of the rotation matrix
      mx=[ ...
         cos(t) -sin(t)
         sin(t) cos(t)
         ];
      % Traslation and rotation of the points A and B
      x1_y1=mx*[x - x_offset(k);y - y_offset(k)]
      x1=x1_y1(1,:);
      y1=x1_y1(2,:);
      % Plot of the rotated line
      ph=plot(x1+x_offset(k),y1+y_offset(k),'b','linewidth',2)
      daspect([1 1 1])
      % xlim([-100 30])
      % ylim([-80 120])
      plot(x1+x_offset(k),y1+y_offset(k),'o','markeredgecolor','b', ...
         'markersize',3,'markerfacecolor','b')
      pause(.05)
      % delete(ph)
   end
   legend('Original','Rotated',-1)
end
```

delete the previous line (using the function `delete`) and drowing the new line.

On MatLab 2015 exists the function `rotx`.

Hope this helps.

**Rotation around point A**
[image]

**Rotation around the origin (0,0)**

[image]

**Rotation around a point of the line**
[image]

Comment: what is the dimension of  `x` and `y` please ? you mean `L1 = m* L` where L is `(x,y)` and `L1=(x1,y1)` ?

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer; x and y are the arrays with the original coordinates. In order to rotate the line around one of its vertices you should first "move" the line to the origin (0;0) then apply the rotation matrix and then move back the line.

Comment: it is not 11 but *l1*.

Comment: if I am drawing `plot( [l1 l1],[20 100], 'r')` that means I have two points `A(l1,20)` and `B(l1,100)`. I still don't get your code but I am working on that ....

Comment: I've further updated the code in the answer. I hope I made it more clear.

Comment: Hello @il_raffa, your code seems broken ??? as you can see from the image (your screenshot) the point A(13 20) haven't moved from it's place !!!!! the rotation is supposed to be around the origin (0,0).

Comment: We don't have to translate A to the origin , because when we will rotate it , it won't work !

Comment: Hello @OSryx, in your question you did not specify to point with respect to which to rotate the line; when I wrote the code to answer to your question I selected the lower point of the line as the point around which to rotate the line. Nevertheless, by means on the `offset` parameter it is possible to rotate the line around any point: I've updated the code by introducing a loop which allows rotating the line around 3 different point (the lower, the origin and a point of the line). The results are shown in the images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that rotate two points around the origin (0,0) and show the result on a plot.

### Updated

```
function [Af,Bf] = rotateTwoPoints (A,B,t)
% Definition of the rotation matrix (rotation around origin (0,0) )
R=[ ...
   cosd(t) -sind(t)
   sind(t) cosd(t)
   ];

% rotation of the points A and B
Af = R*A;
Bf = R*B;

% Plot of the original line
plot(A(1),A(2),'k*', B(1),B(2),'b*');
line([A(1) B(1)],[A(2) B(2)], 'Color','r');

grid on
hold on

% Plot of the rotated line
plot(Af(1),Af(2),'g*', Bf(1),Bf(2),'r*');
line([Af(1) Bf(1)],[Af(2) Bf(2)], 'Color','b');
legend('A','B','line AB','Af','Bf','line AfBf','Location','northeastoutside');
daspect([1 1 1])
```

image rotation of A(13,20) , B(13,100) and t= 10°

```
[Af,Bf] = rotateTwoPoints(A,B,10)
```

[image]